# Toggle class with delay on click

Tags: jquery

I have a button that when clicked on, I want it to toggle the class of another element with a delay. So the logic would be:

1. click the button
2. delay of 500ms
3. add the class
4. click the same button again
5. delay of 500ms
6. remove the class

Here is what i got so far:

```
jQuery(".menu-button").click(function(){
    jQuery(".nav-bar-logo").delay(500).queue(function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-bar-logo-active");
    });
});
```

I know there needs to be a queue when dealing with delays and `addClass` and `removeClass` but it doesn't seem to work with `toggleClass`

The code I got partially works: the class toggles after a delay on the initial click, but when clicking again it doesn't do anything.

Anyone have an idea to fix this?

Comment: `.delay()` is for animation effects. You want `.setTimeout()`

Comment: I assume `this` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: .delay should be fine here, combined with .queue. It has the added benefit of being combined with the queue on subsequent clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments you are looking for `.setTimeout()` instead. And as per your comment below, you want to toggle `.nav-bar-logo`, you can do like this:

```js
jQuery('.menu-button').click(function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.nav-bar-logo').toggleClass('nav-bar-logo-active');
  }, 500);
});
```

Here is a little DEMO

```js
jQuery('.menu-button').click(function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('.nav-bar-logo').toggleClass('nav-bar-logo-active');
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.nav-bar-logo {
  padding: 50px;
  background: red
}

.nav-bar-logo-active {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="menu-button">
  toggle button
</button>
<div class="nav-bar-logo">
  I'm going to change color when button toggled
</div>
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer but I would like to target the class on a seperate element called `nav-bar-logo`

Answer (score 1):

`this` is not available because it's in a delayed function, but we can access the click event:

```
jQuery(".menu-button").click(function(){
        window.setTimeout(function(){
                jQuery('.nav-bar-logo').toggleClass("nav-bar-logo-active");
            }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: hello, same comment I made on the above. i need to target the class on a seperate element. thanks for the answer thought i didnt know about `this` not being available in the delayed functino

Comment: Then we don't need the event. I was reading this as a little more complex than it is. `window.setTimeout` should suit your needs for a delayed action.

Comment: thank you for your answer! this is essentially what the guy above did and he provided an example so i had to accept his. i upvoted you though